# Asterisk: format of the lines logged

Tags: asterisk

What is the format for the "full" log? For example -

```
[Jan 11 09:00:46] VERBOSE[8633][C-00063bc8] pbx.c: ......
```

I understand the date, the level, but what is the "[8633]" and "[C-00063bc8]" and can I grab that information and put it in my sql database so I can look up the call in the log for debugging? Its not the unique id (wish it was), not the channel name, so is it something I can grab off a channel variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look into [source code](https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/main/logger.c#L373):

```
    snprintf(buf, size, "[%s] %s[%d]%s %s: %s",
          msg->date, msg->level_name, msg->lwp, call_identifier_str,
          msg->file, msg->message);
```

In your example `8633` is an LWPID (id of asterisk light-weight process) for this call, you can watch them via `htop` for example.

And `C-00063bc8` is a call identifier ([see details](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Unique+Call-ID+Logging)) in hex. Not sure if it is possible to get this id inside dialplan.

If you want to make some logs processing, you may want to enable JSON log format ([see here](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-25425)) and feed your logs into some database (mongodb or elasticsearch).

If you dump `${UNIQUEID}` to your log somewhere during your dialplan with `NOP` command, you may later find corresponding log call-id and UNIQUEID to identify the call in your logs.

Comment: That is exactly what I was wondering. I did Noop the uniqueid to find it and then I could get the identifier and re-search the file. I was hoping to do it in one step. For simplicity, I just grep the unique id, get the call identifier and then grep it. I was hoping to do that within java, but with log files into the gigabytes grep seemed to be a better idea.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been searching for Asterisk sources for hours to find where the full log is being written. And I was looking for it just to understand what those parameters were at the beginning of each line (I would need something similar even in AMI events). Your answer is very helpful.